# How to fix Google Apps for Business reverification failures?

Tags: google-workspace, site-verification

We have one member of the company using Google Apps for Business so he can use the Google SMTP server with domain email.

We verified him as an owner of the domain by uploading an HTML file to the root of the website. We clicked the provided link and were told that he was successfully verified.

But now, on the verification page inside Webmaster tools. I see a long list of failed verification attempts. The method column says either "Google Analytics" or "Meta tag".

When we log into Google Apps for Business, it says "Domain is verified. Mail set up is pending." We aren't going to set up the email because we aren't going to move all users to Google Apps.

Is there somewhere in Google Apps to specify what verification method to use? Or is Google going to keep trying every single day to re-verify by the other methods?

Comment: Can you confirm you still have all whatever verification methods you used still in place? for example if you uploaded a file are they still present? if you used meta are they still present, if you used DNS are they still present? it should only fail if you remove those.

Comment: I'd upvote that as an answer, bybe.

Comment: He tried a number of verification methods unsuccessfully before he contacted me. We successfully verified him using an HTML file. That is the only method that was ever successful. I know we need to leave this HTML file in place so that Google can reverify whenever it wants. However, it made no sense that it would try to reverify by methods that were never successful in the first place.

Comment: I just checked. And there are no recent failures. It appears Google stopped trying after about a week.